# Android importing Lib project

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-library

I am trying to import the library project from https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator by doing the following steps

[image]

[image]
[image]

### **After importing the Project i get the following error.**

[image]
[image]

**Not sure how to solve this problem. I am not from a JAVA background so i find it difficult to understand how to resolve this.**

Comment: try clean and build in eclipse...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're 99% of the way there. Two small things:

- The library builds against Android 1.6 by default which you do not have installed which is why you are receiving the two errors in the final screenshot. Changing to 2.2 has no consequence though.
- More importantly, you need to include the Android Compatibility Library in your build path. I have included the latest `.jar` in the `libs/` folder which Eclipse/ADT will usually pick up. In your case it did not so you need to expand the `libs/` folder, right click on `android-support-v4.jar`, and select 'Add to build path'.

Comment: do i need to download the 1.6 version to use the lib. i added the jar to build it all the errors have disappeared. so i am hoping i dont need to download the Android 1.6 version.

Comment: No, compiling against a new version is not a problem. 1.6 is simply the oldest version that the library supports.